# How to set properties for nested components from js (QML)?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I want to set the target property for Connections component from js function. I can set property for Rectangle, because it's the top component, but I can't understand how to do it for nested components.

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import "componentCreation.js" as MyScript

Rectangle {
    if: page
    color: "black"

    Component.onCompleted: MyScript.create(page);
```

**rect.qml**

```
Rctangle {
    color: "white"

    Connections {
        id: connect
        //target:
    }
}
```

**componentCreation.js**

```
function create(parent) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("rect.qml");
    component.createObject(parent, {x: 100, y: 100});
}
```

Comment: You cannot, you should make a property in rect.qml and read from these in your nested components

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, you can try js method for connect "connect" instead of Connections

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. I used your advices and I got it. Here is my implementation:

**rect.qml**

```
Rctangle {
    color: "white"
    property var cnnt: connect

    Connections {
        id: connect
    }
}
```

**componentCreation.js**

```
function create(parent, target) {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("rect.qml");
    var obj = component.createObject(parent, {x: 100, y: 100});
    obj.cnnt.target = target;
}
```